# How do you find out why MacOS has a high load average?

Tags: macos, performance

Recently, I noticed that MacOS (Catalina) is running slow. Apps regularly show the spinning rainbow wheel cursor, and video conference apps don't work. I had a load average of over 20, and after quitting all apps, I could only get it down to 16. Normally I see a load average of 1 to 3, even with all my apps open.

I resorted to rebooting my laptop, costing me hundreds of open windows in several apps.  When the login screen appeared, I SSH'd into it from another machine. Without any graphical logins, the load average was already 13. I couldn't identify any apps that were consuming a lot of resources. There was some daemon that collects data for Spotlight to use, but it was only using 10% CPU according to `top`.

After logging in locally, the load average is back to 15 with just a couple of terminals running, and I'm already getting the rainbow cursor.

There's absolutely nothing suspicious in /var/log/system.log, nor in the output of dmesg.

MacOS has never worked very well, but it's never been *this* bad. How can I find out what it's doing and why?

EDIT: Here's the output of `top` with no local users:

```
Processes: 150 total, 2 running, 148 sleeping, 718 threads                                11:46:13
Load Avg: 11.63, 4.14, 1.62  CPU usage: 0.45% user, 62.52% sys, 37.1% idle
SharedLibs: 219M resident, 26M data, 24M linkedit.
MemRegions: 13721 total, 596M resident, 61M private, 349M shared.
PhysMem: 2847M used (1660M wired), 13G unused.
VM: 711G vsize, 1991M framework vsize, 0(0) swapins, 0(0) swapouts.
Networks: packets: 607/181K in, 917/272K out. Disks: 54410/873M read, 1852/14M written.

PID  COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH    #WQ  #POR MEM    PURG   CMPR PGRP PPID STATE    BOOSTS
287  mdsync       10.9 00:01.59 3      1    43   4524K+ 0B     0B   287  1    sleeping *0[1]
0    kernel_task  4.8  00:52.13 266/12 0    0    37M    0B     0B   0    0    running   0[0]
343  top          3.0  00:00.63 1/1    0    25   1868K  0B     0B   343  293  running  *0[1]
203  airportd     1.1  00:01.68 16     14   175+ 6248K+ 0B     0B   203  1    sleeping  0[10]
188  WindowServer 1.1  00:06.19 9      4    343  109M   1512K  0B   188  1    sleeping *0[1]
216  usbd         0.6  00:00.53 3      2    90+  2992K  0B     0B   216  1    sleeping  0[0]
59   configd      0.4  00:01.94 11     4    330+ 4144K  0B     0B   59   1    sleeping *0[1]
269  SecurityAgen 0.4  00:04.36 3      1    287  248M   2052K  0B   269  1    sleeping *0[1]
49   UserEventAge 0.2  00:01.71 6      3    410  4184K  0B     0B   49   1    sleeping *0[1]
1    launchd      0.1  00:03.21 3      2    1433 10M    0B     0B   1    0    sleeping  0[0]
58   systemstats  0.1  00:01.04 3      2    97   4132K+ 0B     0B   58   1    sleeping  0[1]
106  AirPlayXPCHe 0.1  00:00.62 6      3    167+ 4132K+ 0B     0B   106  1    sleeping *0[1]
143  contextstore 0.1  00:00.90 4      3    107+ 5232K+ 236K   0B   143  1    sleeping  0[52]
96   PerfPowerSer 0.1  00:02.70 8      5    275  9912K  256K   0B   96   1    sleeping  0[14]
218  VDCAssistant 0.0  00:00.17 2      1    28   2856K  0B     0B   218  1    sleeping *0[1]
61   powerd       0.0  00:00.82 3      2    100  2676K  0B     0B   61   1    sleeping *0[1]
107  notifyd      0.0  00:00.62 2      1    137  972K   0B     0B   107  1    sleeping *0[1]
102  bluetoothd   0.0  00:00.51 3      2    111+ 4132K  0B     0B   102  1    sleeping *0[1]
292  sshd         0.0  00:00.01 1      0    19   1036K  0B     0B   288  288  sleeping *0[1]
251  TouchBarServ 0.0  00:00.47 4      1    254  12M    5888K  0B   251  1    sleeping *0[1]
103  hidd         0.0  00:00.86 6      2    268  3076K  0B     0B   103  1    sleeping *0[1]
```

Comment: Check the Activity Monitor app (in `/Applications/Utilities`). It's similar to `top`, but with a nice GUI. You can use it to find out which apps have high CPU, memory, energy or network usage. You write "costing me hundreds of open windows in several apps" - you can configure macOS to restore windows when opening an app, just uncheck "Close windows when quitting an app" in System Preferences > General (when shutting down or restarting your Mac, select "Reopen windows when logging back in").

Comment: Can you run ` top -o cpu` and copy/paste the first 10 lines into the question as text (formatted as code)?

Comment: jaume, the only app on MacOS that is capable of restoring its state is the Web browser. All other apps make such crude attempts to restore state that it's not even worth the trouble. I end up having to close the apps' attempts to recover and do it manually.

Comment: nohillside, I've booted the Mac into Recovery Mode, and the load average is 11.44 even in that minimal environment! The most CPU-intensive process is WindowServer. At this point I'm beginning to suspect a hardware fault.

Comment: What model of Mac is this? How long has it been doing this?

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro, year of manufacture unknown (employer-issued). I just noticed the problem today. Earlier this week the load average got high, but I got it under control by killing processes. Today is when it got unmanageable.

Comment: Dust could be an issue. But if you want people here to offer more insights, please add details about the actual usage numbers.

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount You write "All other apps make such crude attempts to restore state that it's not even worth the trouble", I'm suprised and sorry to read that, I can't help but wonder which are those apps... (in Monterey, it works nicely with all apps I use, including Evernote, Mail , Xcode, Preview, Pages, Terminal, CotEditor and Safari).

Comment: What does it say about the details of the Mac in "About this Mac" from the Apple menu?

Comment: nohillside, I got the `top` output.

Comment: "About this Mac" says "MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this type of behavior is observed when there is a hardware problem. Often this is due to either a problem with the disk system (i.e. drive or controller) or lack of proper cooling (i.e. failed fan).

I would suggest ensuring that you have proper backups, then try to inspect the fans and clean them. Or alternatively send it in for repairs (or consider a new laptop if the current one is really old).

Comment: It was a hardware fault. I don't remember what the problem was, but it was covered by the warranty. They wiped the hard drive, unfortunately.